# Why won't my android video player display media in the correct aspect ratio

Tags: screen, media-player

I'm using a Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S) and when I play M4V video files, ostensibly formatted for IPhone, the device stretches the image to fit the screen rather than letterboxing.  I can't find any option to change this.  Is there a better media player or a hidden setting?

Answer (score 1):

I use [RockPlayer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.freecoder.android.cmplayer.v7) and it has a button right on the display to toggle aspect ratios and zoom levels--very convenient.